# Problem changing from html h3 tag to h4 from css boostrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a h3 tag in html like this:

```
<div class="centrar">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor!</h3>
</div>
```

i need to change it to H4 from css, but no works. this what i have tried.

```
.centrar h3 {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

but it continues with size and bolded as h3. 
A rule is no touch html. i have to achieve it from css only.

Comment: Why are you not using h4 tag ?

Comment: cuz the idea is to make it from css instead of html

Comment: I don't understand your use case but try inspecting h3 and h4 and see how through CSS you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here:

```
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
font-weight: normal !important;
font-size: 24px !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update in both your HTML and CSS like this:

```css
.centrar h4 {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 17px; // change the size to whatever you want here
}
```

```html
<div class="centrar">
  <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor!</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: i cant touch html. is a rule. i have to achieve from css just.

Comment: You would need javascript at that point. There is no way to turn one tag into another tag using CSS.  However you can adjust styles of the original tag `h3` however you want. Id `font-size` and `font-weight` all you are concerned about or is there another reason altogether the tags must change to `h4`?

Comment: when i replace font-size y a bigger or smaller nothing change

Comment: i wanna change it in order to have the same aspects as h4, but keeping h3 in html

Comment: I have just updated the code example. If you run the snippet you will see the font-size is indeed changing. If it is not changing in your project then there is possibly some other CSS that is targeting this element with more specificity.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set another font-size in this case.

h1, h2, h3, h4, etc. are still normal paragraphs with specific styling (and other tags) but the behaviour is still the same.

I would change the h3 in this case. Maybe you got a template-language like smarty or twig and could use an if to change the tag or class.